# How to add attachments to emails with sprout forms

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I am trying to add file attachments on the notification emails sent out by sprout forms plugin. Looking in the docs it looks like I need to add hidden config setting within the plugin.

I have created a config.php file in the plugin directory and put the following code in it:

```
<?php

return array(

'sproutForms' => 'enableFileAttachments',

);
```

However, when I receive a notification email it still doesn't have the attachment. Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` tag?

Comment: Hi Alec, yep I've added that to my form. Everything saves correctly, asset is uploaded,notification email is sent and shows the name of the file but the only thing not happening is the asset being attached to the email

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is to do with the config because of the message in the sprout forms log file: 2015/06/23 08:39:08 [info] [plugin] File attachments are currently not enabled for Sprout Forms.

Comment: Oh okay, instead of adding a `config.php` into the plugin folder, have you tried adding it to your `general.php` config?

Comment: Just tried that again but no luck I'm afraid

Comment: Probably worth pinging the Barrel Strength Design team to clarify if it's a bug or just a config setting you're missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your on the right track but there may be a couple issues that we need to address:

1. The hidden config setting should be set in the `craft/config/general.php` file
2. The `enableFileAttachments` config setting should also be within an array and set to `true`:

   ```
   return array(
     'sproutForms' => array(
       'enableFileAttachments' => true,
     )
   );
   ```

*Note: As of this posting, we handle this functionality as a hidden config setting because we are still refining it's behavior. At some point, this will likely be easier to do directly from the Control Panel.*